# How to figure out if there is only 100mi of course space left in the names page.. I have access to KubernetesClient object

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubectl, fabric8-kubernetes-client

How to get the limits.cpu value from kubernetesClient object. I need to check the cpu quota before creating a new pod in kubernetes. (JAVA)

I came across Client.top.node... but I need some equivalent of
Kubectl describe quota

Basic ask is to check if there is 100mi of quota left before creating a pod

Comment: if you set `100mi` as the requested CPU in pod resource definition it will create only pod when there is quota available to assign to that pod.

Comment: My requirement is to trigger a mail to admins if the space is decreasing.  So want to read values in the resources quota

Comment: not java guy but might be helpful : https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient/resourceQuotas